# How to I change the Interpolation Type in the Map Range node like the documentation says?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, mathematics, interpolation

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/map_range.html), you should be able to change the Interpolation Type of a Map Range node. I am on 2.91.2 and don't see it. Is this a new feature that I don't yet have access to?

[image]

Secondly, is it possible to create my own interpolation curve using math nodes instead? I am trying to remap a value that doesn't progress from 0-1 linearly so that it does follow a more linear range in implementation.

Keep in mind this is all in the shader editor, not compositor.

Gracious thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are on the shader editor. In 2.9.12  the interpolation options are there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it more intuitive to use an *RGB Curve* node once you've normalized the value using *Map Range*.

[image]